# How to setup cPanels Global Email Filters to filter multiple rules for one e-mail address?

Tags: email, cpanel, spam, linux, filtering

I'm using `cPanel 106.0 (build 11)` on a Linux server with x86_64 architecture, Apache 2.4.54 and PHP 8.1.13.

I'm using the `Global Email Filters` feature to filter e-mails.

I want to create a filter that filters an e-mail with Subject=aaa OR Subject=bbb OR Subject=ccc but only if To=test@example.com.

So I want to filter if: `To=test@example.com AND (Subject=aaa OR Subject=bbb OR Subject=ccc)`

How can I do that?

I already tried the following but I'm not sure if it's the right way:

[image: cPanel Global Email Filters]